# How can I find matchings in a Bipartite graph beginning with specific vertices?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, bipartite-matching

Context: I'm modelling kidney exchanges through directed acyclic graphs. I convert these to Bipartite graphs (by splitting each node into a donor and receiver, and the edge from the original graph exist between corresponding donors and receivers). I want a way to find maximum number of edges through disjoint chains and I've been trying to do so through maximum wtd matching.

I know I can use ford-fulkerson to find a maximum wtd perfect matching, however, the main problem I'm facing is that the matchings can only exist for chains beginning with *specific* vertices. For example, if this is my directed acyclic graph:

[image]

Turning this into a Bipartite graph and using the maximum wtd matching way, I get the chain 0->1->3->5->6 but I also get 2->4. However, I can only have chains beginning with 0 so 2->4 should not come up.

I wanted to know if there were any ways to work around this problem? Someone suggested making this a minimum cost perfect matching problem but I'm confused how.

I realise this is a weird question but any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If you have just one starting vertex, you can do this quite easily by looking for the longest path in a DAG beginning with that vertex (this is the Critical Path problem -- solvable in linear time using dynamic programming for directed *acyclic* graphs, but NP-hard for general directed or undirected graphs).  If you have more than one, I think you could solve this as a max flow problem: create a new source vertex with capacity-1 edges to each starting vertex, set all existing edges to also have capacity 1, and find the maximum flow.

Comment: Okay so this is in line with what I've been thinking, which is a positive for me, however here are a couple of issues: 1. There can be multiple starting vertices. For example in the graph above I could have a new vertex, say A, which has an edge from A to 3. Then I have two starting points, 0 and A. 2. It's mainly the capacities I'm confused by. For example, when I make my bipartite graph I split the vertices as said above, what should I keep as the capacity for such edges? Should I not have such an edge? In such a max flow problem, does the source only have edges joining the starting nodes?

Answer (score 2):

To make this a minimum-cost perfect matching problem, split each node as you indicated (sending/receiving).  Add a high-cost edge from each node's sending node to its own receiving node.  This high-cost edge will only be used if that node does not receive a kidney.  Additionally, I assume Node 0 in the above graph is supposed to be an altruistic donor or a deceased organ donor that does not need to receive a kidney.  (Otherwise, your example has no cycles and no exchange can take place.)  Assuming Node 0 is a 1-way donor, add low cost edges from **every** sending node to Node 0's receiving node.

Then solve the minimum-cost perfect matching problem.  A perfect matching is obviously possible (every sending node can send to its own receiving node).  A minimum-cost perfect matching will use as few of the high-cost edges as possible.  Minimizing the number of high-cost edges (nodes that send to themselves) is the same as maximizing the number of nodes that receive a kidney.

This is also known as the assignment problem and can be solved in polynomial time.  Most kidney-exchange research adds the significant complication of requiring cycles to be at most length k.  That complication makes the problem NP-hard.  Altruistic donors could allow for longer cycles in practice.